# Curious behaviour of inverse modulo

Tags: c++, primes, factorial, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I wrote the following code to calculate n!modulo p...Given that n and p are close...but its running in a rather funny way, cant figure out the bug..There is some overflow somewhere..The constraints are 1 < P <= 2*10^9

1 <= N <= 2*10^9
though it runs fine for few cases...what could be the error.I have used

```
(a/b)mod p = ((a mod p)*(b^(p-2))mod p)mod p
```

as `p` is prime....and wilsons theorem that `(p-1)! mod p = p-1`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define _ ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);
using namespace std;
unsigned int pow(unsigned int a, unsigned n,unsigned int p) {
unsigned int ret = 1;
while(n) {
if((n&1)== 1) ret=(ret*a)%p;
a=a%p;
a=(a*a)%p;
 n=n>>1;
}
return ret;
}
int main(){_
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    unsigned int n,p;
    long long int r;
    cin>>n>>p;
    r=p-1;
    if(n>=p){
        cout<<"0\n";
    }
    else{
        for(unsigned int i=p-1;i>n;i--){
            r=((long long)r*pow(i,p-2,p))%p;

        }
        cout<<r<<"\n";
    }
}   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define _ ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);` o.O I've never seen *such* a macro (I mean, I know what it's intended to do, but the identifier used... leaves me speechless)

Comment: I think your `a*=a` is overflowing. [Proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d020314a5dbd23f6)

Comment: Yes you are right it was indeed overflowing

Comment: though it shows right answer for 21!mod71 now but it overflows for other numbers within the constraints specified, where is the overflow occurring?

Comment: Add tracers like `cout<<"pow called with("<<a<<", "<<n<<", "<<p<<")\n";` and in the loop `cout<<"\ta: "<<a<<"\n";` and so on to see what happens. You can also test for overflows `if(a > numeric_limits<decltype(a)>::max()/2) cout<<"overflow";`

Answer (score 1):

21! is 51090942171709440000, while 2^64 is only 1844674407370955161: so if `unsigned long long` is a 64-bit quantity (as is likely), it doesn't fit.

Comment: i havent calculated 21!i am taking cumulative mods so that the number never gets greater than p